# Interview: deleting a node in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Does this implementation of node delete works, or it my fail ?

```
void remove_node(node *p)
{
    node **i = &node_list;

    for (;(*i) != NULL && ((*i) != p); *i = ((*i)->next)) ;

    if (*i != NULL) 
    {
      (*i) = (*i)->next;
    }

    if (p != NULL) 
    {
      free(p);
    }
}
```

BTW, as far as I know, in every algorithm I saw that deletes a node from a list,
there was a variable that was supposed to keep the previous pointer. this implementation lacks this...

Comment: Looks like you're moving forward the same way you're deleting. Also, a while loop may boost the readability.

Comment: I think you should try write it in a readable way and try not to be sophisticated...

Comment: @0x90 This is an interview question, I didn't write it like that, and yes, it's supposed to be sophisticated

Comment: @Mellowcandle removing a node in a linkedlist is a simple question, sorry for disappointing you :( I am happy you didn't write it like that, cause one write code like that probably didn't write much code in his life...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `parameter p as pArg`
**After for loop :-**

```
for (;(*i) != NULL && ((*i) != p); *i = ((*i)->next)) ;
```

> *i=pArg [if node pArg exists in linked list](case 1) or *i=NULL(case 2)

**After first if:-**

```
 if (*i != NULL) 
    {
      (*i) = (*i)->next;
    }
```

> p=pArg->next (case 1) and no operation in (case 2)

**After second if:-**

```
if (p != NULL) 
    {
      free(p);
    }
```

> free(pArg->next);(case 1) ; and no operation in (case 2)(if pArg really is a node in the LL)

*You deleted the node pointed by pArg and **not the pArg** itself*.

Make a little change:-

```
node *prevp=NULL;

for (;(*i) != NULL && ((*i) != p); *i = ((*i)->next))
{prevp=*i;} 

if (*i != NULL) 
    {
      prevp->next = (*i)->next;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No. It doesn't work. (yes I know, I cheated - initially I said it did).

As an interview question answer I'd start by listing the assumptions:

- node_list starts out valid (and correctly NULL terminated)
- it is a singly linked list
- nodes are dynamically allocated

Issues are:
Loop will stop when `*i == p`.  It needs to stop when `*i->next == p` - then it would almost work, but still have problems if p is the first node in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Mistakes in your program are

1. head pointer(node_list) will not point the first element, it will point the element next to `p`
2. `(*i) = (*i)->next` - this is wrong. Previous node`s next pointer should be updated.

Below updated logic will work fine

```
void remove_node(node *p) 
{     
    node *i = node_list;      
    node *previous_node = NULL;

    if((NULL == p) || (NULL == node_list))
    {
        return;
    }

    for (; (i != NULL) && (i != p); i = i->next) 
    {
        previous_node = i;
    }

    if (i != NULL)      
    {       
        if(NULL == previous_node) // `p` is the first node
        {
            node_list = i->next;
            free(i);
        }
        else //`p` is not the first node
        {
            previous_node->next = i->next;     
            free(i);
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: what kind of an answer is it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work with side effect that `node_list` won't be pointing to start of the list. So head node need to be stored in some other variable.

BTW, have you tried it? what do you get?